# Sqlite3 in C, running multiple queries

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm writing a C program and running multiple queries with sqlite. I'm not using `sqlite3_exec()` as you can't retrieve results without writing a callback function for it.

So I have source that looks something like this:

```
char * query = "CREATE TABLE 'items' (id int, icon int, name text); CREATE TABLE 'icons' (id int, image blob); CREATE TABLE 'playfields' (id int, name text);";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(dump_db_into,query,-1,&sqlstmt,0);
sqlite3_step(sqlstmt);
```

And of course, only the first query is executed. Do I need to run `sqlite3_step()` multiple times?

I'd rather avoid having to run these commands over and over if I have a large amount of queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found in the references, my bad:

> These routines only compile the first statement in zSql, so *pzTail is left pointing to what remains uncompiled.