# Creating multiple tables with single query statement using swift

Tags: ios, sql, swift

I am trying to create two tables with a single query statement. However, below code is creating just 'myprofile' table only. It doesn't create 'groups' table. Am I missing something here? Can someone please help.

```
let createTableString = """
                    CREATE TABLE `myprofile` (`profile_id` VARCHAR , `first_name` VARCHAR , `profile_type` VARCHAR ,`preferences` VARCHAR);
                    CREATE TABLE `groups` (`account_id` VARCHAR ,`unique_url` VARCHAR, `title` VARCHAR, `participant_id` VARCHAR ,`create_date` VARCHAR,`synced` VARCHAR);
    """

private func createTable() {
      var createTableStatement: OpaquePointer?
      if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, createTableString, -1, &createTableStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
          if sqlite3_step(createTableStatement) == SQLITE_DONE {
              print("\table's are created.")
          } else {
              print("\table's are not created.")
        }
      } else {
          print("\nCREATE TABLE statement is not prepared.")
      }

      sqlite3_finalize(createTableStatement)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9144869/3141234

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift sqlite How to run multiple queries (inserts, updates, etc) in one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245169/swift-sqlite-how-to-run-multiple-queries-inserts-updates-etc-in-one-string)

Comment: Thank you so much. Using sqlite3_exec worked.